# Text detection in Image with Pytesseract in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I am new to Pytesseract and currently in learning phase.

Here is the image:

[image]

from which I am trying to extract the text. The smaller text "movlmento, destmo" that I thought would be difficult to extract was easily extracted but the more bigger and visible text "TO" is not being extracted. I have searched all over but was not able to figure out a solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!
Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as p

p.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

img = Image.open('sample.jpg')
img = img.convert('1', dither=Image.NONE)

img2 = p.image_to_string(img)
print(img2)
```

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: I have added the code now @seralouk